# Open and write file in nasm for Windows 64bit

Tags: windows, 64-bit, nasm

Please help me to solve the problem. The file is created but not written. When it goes to the stage of recording a file, the programme slows down a bit. I expect a recorded file to be created, but it is created empty.

```
DEFAULT REL

global main

extern CreateFileA
extern CloseHandle
extern WriteFile

section .data 
    filename db "f.txt", 0

section .text 
main: 
    sub rsp, 48h

    mov rcx, filename   
    mov dword [rsp+40], 40000000h | 2 
    xor r9d, r9d       
    xor r8d, r8d      
    mov dword [rsp+32], 2 
    mov edx, 2
    сall CreateFileA
    
    mov rdx, rax
    
    mov rcx, rdx
    lea rdx, [filename]
    mov r8, 6
    mov r9, 0
    call WriteFile
    
    mov rcx, rdx
    call CloseHandle
    
    xor eax,eax 
    add rsp, 48h
    ret
```

Comment: Your code doesn't check for errors, and there are lots of them. Read the documentation of WriteFile and check that you are passing the correct parameters (and the correct number of them).

Comment: I rewrote the code to write the file, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: mov     rcx, rax
mov     rdx, filename
mov     r8, len
xor     r9, r9
mov dword [rsp + 32], 0

Comment: "This parameter [lpNumberOfBytesWritten] can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL." You are still not checking for errors. And you are passing a garbage value to CloseHandle.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is.....

Comment: call CreateFileA
 
 mov rdi, rax
 
 mov     rcx, rdi             ; hFile
 mov     rdx, filename        ; lpBuffer
 mov     r8, len              ; nNumberOfBytesToWrite
    lea     r9, [bytes_written]  ; lpNumberOfBytesWritten
 mov dword [rsp + 32], 0      ; lpOverlapped
 
 call WriteFile
 
 test rax, rax
 
    mov rcx, rdi
    call CloseHandle
 
 xor eax,eax
 add rsp, 48h
    ret

Comment: You still aren't checking for errors. And you made enough changes that it doesn't assemble any more. You are also failing to preserve a callee-preserved register. I think the way to go is to write the code in C and then read and understand the assembly code that a compiler produces.